# How to change the background color of a row in wpf datagridview?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview

I have a data grid view created with WPF. And i have already set the items source for the grid view. And also i got a text box and a button. When i put the row index to the text box and presses the button that particular row with index should be displayed with some color. I'm new to WPF, so How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you select the row based on its row index by using ContainerFromIndex() method:

```
DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)dataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(row_index);
```

Finally set background on row:

```
row.Background = Brushes.Red;
```